# why i get one date and the code displays another

Tags: android, date, kotlin, retrofit2

I use retrofit in my mobile application. To format the date I use setDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-DD HH: mm: ss.S") and when I get the mounth it is not displayed correctly in the code and on the screen

I tried different conversion patterns but they didn’t work (MM, mm, MMM,MMMM)

```
val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S")
            .setLenient()
            .registerTypeAdapter(TypeOfPoint::class.java, TypeOfPointDeserializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(TypeOfStatus::class.java,TypeOfStatusDeserializer())
            .create()
```

I get 2019-07-05 10: 59: 31.000000 and in code 2019-01-05T10: 59: 31.000 + 0300

Comment: can you tell what date is input and what output you want?

Comment: @ParasVerma  2019-07-05 10: 59: 31.000000 this date input аnd this date I would like to see at the output no matter what format

Answer (score 0):

In this function you have to pass the date as string and it will return date in Jan 01,2019 format. You can change the format as per the requirement.

```
public static String formatDate(String date_s) {
    SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    form.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = form.parse(date_s);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat form1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy"));
    return form1.format(date);

}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn’t write well because I don’t know English well, but this is not what I need. The date 2019-07-05 comes to me, my GsonBuilder () for some reason displays it as 2019-01-5, only the month changes.I want to understand why. I hope google translate helped me translate correctly :D